# Does my tire need to be replaced?

Tags: tires

There is a reasonably large cut in the tread that looks a little concerning to me (see photos below). Should I get the tire replaced?

[image: Cut in tire]
[image: Cut in tire closeup]

Answer (score 2):

It's often hard to tell just from a picture. But this cut looks to be on the "meaty" part of the tire, so it shouldn't be an issue. Ask a tire shop to take a quick look. They may recommend you just buy a tube of rubber cement and pour it in there the seal the cut.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that and post back here with any update.

Comment: The cement idea is fine - as long as the cords or plies are not exposed - if the cut is just into the rubber then you should be fine. If it goes to the plies then new tyre....